# can not addRange of items to var using linq and c#

Tags: linq

I have a following list of users:

```
var roles = userRoleRepository.Get(q => q.user_id.Equals(username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

roles has two properties one is (ID,Name) ,how can i add a collection to this after i get the list?since roles,does not have add or addrange,i want to add("124","Jack")

Comment: There's no LINQ code in this snippet. Just a `Get` method from a repository class defined in your code and a lambda that only performs a string comparison

Comment: @TimSchmelter is it possible to add to the roles?although its a var

Comment: @mrslt add the roles to *what* ? `var` isn't some special type. What does `Get` return? Who wrote it? If it returns an array or IEnumerable you can't add anything to it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  the var i am getting is containg userId and Name,but if i want to add something to this list i have to convert it toList(),but  roles.toList().add("124","Jack") still not work,roles is the name of my var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that `UserRoleRepository` is an object of one of your (company's) own classes. This class has a `Get` function that has some return value.

Alas you forgot to tell us the returned type. From the code snippet, I assume that the returned object is not a sequence of objects, but one single object, probably something that you'd call a `UserRole`. The returned `UserRole` is the one in the `userRoleRepository` that has a `user_id` that equals some string `userName`.

As the `Get` function returns only one `UserRole` it is not a meaningful action to add a collection to this one object, unless this `UserRole` has a function to add a collection. But as you told us: your `UserRole` does not have such a function.

Or are you a bit sloppy in your description and do you want to add some `UserRoles` to the collection of `UserRoles` that would be the return of your `Get` function? Alas again: you didn't give us a definition of the return value of your `Get` function.

If `Get` returns one `UserRole` and you want the combination of this fetched `UserRole` together with your own sequence of `UserRoles`, do the following:

```
UserRole fetchedUserRole = userRoleRepository.Get(...);
List<UserRole> userRoles = new List<UserRole>();
userRoles.Add(fetchedUserRole);
return userRoles.Concat(myOwnUserRoleCollection);
```

If on the other hand `Get` returns a sequence of `USerRole`, the code would be even simpler:

```
IEnumerable<UserRole> fetchedUserRoles = userRoleRepository.Get(...);
return fetchedUserRoles.Concat(myOwnUserRoleCollection);
```